# Zend config.ini parameters referred from a script

Tags: php, zend-framework, config

Zend framework talk.I knew that:

```
"When referring to configuration parameters within a script,
 you'll prefix it with $this->config and converting the periods 
 to right-facing arrows"
```

**ISSUE:** However when I try to echo "$this->config->website->url;" I dont have output.

If I try with "$this->config[website][url]" I receive the correct output.

Where Am I wrong?

I have:

my **bootstrap class**:

```
[..]

    protected function _initConfig() 
{     
    $config =$this->getOptions();// contents of config file
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);     
    return $config; 

}   
protected function _initAction()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH."\My\Helper",'My_Action_Helper');
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Initializer');


}
```

my **My_Action_Helper_Initializer**:

```
class My_Action_Helper_Initializer extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
 public function init()
 {
    $controller=$this->getActionController();
    $controller->config=Zend_registry::get('config');

 }  

}
```

my **IndexController**:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
 {
  echo $this->config[website][url];//it outputs the correct value
  echo $this->config->website->url;//NO OUTPUT!  
 }
}
```

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a whirl :)

Bootstrap :

```
protected function _initConfig(){
    $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions(), true);
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    return $config;
}
```

And where you want to use it :

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
```

You were storing an array in options not an an object (Zend_Config)

Comment: $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions(), true); being the important bit.

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
 $this->config[website][url];
```

Your accessing the config parmeters as an array, this is working for you, so use it?

When using

```
 $this->config->website->url;
```

Your accessing the config as if it is an object, this is failing, so don't use it?

If it works one way then what is the problem, do you **need** to use the object notation for the config parameters?

Comment: Well I'm referencing a book.Not finding What the author wrote I should,put me on alert..I was unprepared so I want to understand why this issue is happening? You have any idea?=)